# Allowing unordered elements in dynamic XSD for web service?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I have an application, where the user can design a web service with dynamic data. The user can specify the data which the webservice should handle. 
For example, the user defines this data:

```
PERSON (minoccurs 1, maxoccurs 1)
   -> Firstname (minoccurs 1, maxoccurs 1)
   -> Lastname (minoccurs 1, maxoccurs 1)
   -> email (minoccurs 0, maxoccurs 3)
```

So the XML can look like this

```
<Person>
    <Firstname>Peter</Firstname>
    <Lastname>Last</Lastname>
    <Email>email1@example.com</Email>
    <Email>email2@example.com</Email>
 </Person>
```

In my application, I generate an XSD for the XML, where I am using sequence to deal with the elements. This works fine, but now the customer wants to send the data in any order, so I thought of using `xs:all`, but there `maxOccurs` can be only 1. I know with XSD 1.1 `xs:all` is capable of handling `maxOccurs` greater one. Is there a way in XSD 1.0 to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this particular case, you could add an `email-list` wrapper around `email`,

```
PERSON (minoccurs 1, maxoccurs 1)
   -> Firstname (minoccurs 1, maxoccurs 1)
   -> Lastname (minoccurs 1, maxoccurs 1)
   -> email-list (minoccurs 1, maxoccurs 1)      
      -> email (minoccurs 0, maxoccurs 3)
```

and still use `xsd:all` in XSD 1.0, but you're not going to be able to use XSD 1.0 as the target in the general case without reflecting `xsd:all`'s limitations in similar constraints on your input language.

So, as answered to your [previous question regarding XSD and unordered elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37855441/290085), you really ought to consider relaxing the orderless aspect of your interface.